# How do I do authorization check on ComponentWillMount?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

My website have a few pages that is protected by login. My current solution to this is:

in app.js:

```
<div className="app">
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={appHistory} onUpdate={fireTracking}>
                <Route name="main" component={AppHandler}>
                    <Route name="home" path="/" component={HomePageHandler}/>
                </Route>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    </div>
```

And then my HomePageHandler is:

```
export default class HomePageHandler extends BaseAuthorizedComponent {  
    render() {
        return (
            <div>hello</div>
        )
    }
}
```

As the HomePageHandler extends BaseAuthorizedComponent, which is defined as:

```
class BaseAuthorizedComponent extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        if (!this.props.user.signed_in) {
            this.context.router.push('/signin')
        }
    }
}

HomePageHandler.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

function select(state) {
    return {
        user: state.user,
    }
}
export default connect(select)(BaseAuthorizedComponent)
```

The redux's user object has a flag that indicates if the user is logged in or not. The idea is that on the homepage, before the component is mounted, the BaseAuthorizedComponent would have checked and redirect to signin page if user is not logged in. My idea is to let every page that requires authorization to extend BaseAuthorizedComponent.

However the following error happens when trying to load the homepage:

```
Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(BaseAuthorizedComponent)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(BaseAuthorizedComponent)".
```

No idea how can I fix the problem while keeping the advantage of a single place to check authorization. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't this be `BaseAuthorizedComponent.contextTypes` (instead of `HomePageHandler.contextTypes`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research, the best way I've seen is this:

```
<Route name="name" 
path="/path" 
component={THeWorkHandler} 
onEnter={requireAuth}/>
```

And the requireAuth is put in a helper file:

```
export function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
    if (!(//logic to see if user is logged in )) {
        replace({pathname: '/user/signin'});
    }
}
```

This way if a onEnter requireAuth determines that the user is not authenticated, it will redirect to /user/signin page.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you is better to use composition instead of inheritance https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Next,  you can add "push" action creator from react-router-redux (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) to mapDispatchToProps function:

```js
function composeAuth = (ComposedComponent) => {
    class BaseAuthorizedComponent extends React.Component {
        // We use componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount, cause componentWillMount is deprecated https://medium.com/@baphemot/whats-new-in-react-16-3-d2c9b7b6193b
        componentDidMount() {
            if (!this.props.user.signed_in) {
                this.props.push('/signin');
            }
        }
        
        render() {
            if (!this.props.user.signed_in) {
               return null;
            }
            
            return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
        }
    }
    
    return connect(state => ({user: state.user}), {push})(BaseAuthorizedComponent);
}

class HomePageHandler extends React.Component {  
    render() {
        return (
            <div>hello</div>
        )
    }
}

export default composeAuth(HomePageHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
class CheckAuth extends React.Component{
   state = {
      auth: false
   }
   render(){
      return(
         {this.state.auth ? <div>Authorized user</div> : <div>Unauthorized user</div>}
      )
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
      auth: state.auth
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CheckAuth);
```

And then include it in your other components like so:

```
import CheckAuth from './CheckAuth';
...
class Home extends React.Component{
   render(){
      return(
        <div>
           <CheckAuth />
           Hello world!!
        </div>
      )
   }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: I agree that in case of auth and security, composition is better than inheritance. But auth should be a feature rather than a "Component" and that's why I don't like the idea of making it one. In fact, I later figured out a better way to do what I wanted, and I have put it in my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, the easiest way to satisfy my requirement is:

in an util file:

```
export function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
    // use your own method to check if user is logged in or not
    if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        replace({pathname: '/signin'});
    }
}
```

and then import this method in the app.js file and use it:

```
<div className="app">
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={appHistory} onUpdate={fireTracking}>
                <Route name="main" component={AppHandler}>
                    <Route name="home" path="/" component={HomePageHandler} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
                </Route>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    </div>
```

In this way if the user requires auth(isLoggedIn() is false), then it will redirect the page to /signin.